# Show that: $ x_{1}^n + x_{2}^n + · · · + x_{n}^n ≥ nx_{1} x_{2} · · · x_{n} $.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, jensen-inequality

> Let $ x_{1}, x_{1}, x_{2}, · · ·, x_{n} $ be positive reals. Show that: $ x_{1}^n + x_{2}^n + · · · + x_{n}^n ≥ nx_{1} x_{2} · · · x_{n} $. If $ x_{1} x_{2} · · · x_{n} = 1 $ then $ x_{1} + x_{2} + · · · + x_{n} ≥ n $.

I am trying to do this problem using Holder's inequality. Also I want to use a reasoning similar to the following exercise: $ x_1, x_2, ..., x_n \in \mathbb R $ are nonegative and $ k \in \mathbb R $, $ k \geq 1 $. Prove that if $ x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = n $, then $ x_1^k + x_2^k + ... + x_n^k \geq n $. I tried to find the smallest value of $ x_1^k + ... + x_n^k $ and it turned out to be $ n $ for $ x_1 = ... = x_n = 1 $. Am I doing this correct?

Comment: This is just AM-GM inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AM-GM:$$ \frac{x_1^n+x_2^n+x_3^n+...+x_n^n}{n} \ge (x_1^n x_2^n x_3^n....x_n^n)^{1/n}$$

Comment: I don't understand why you consider the sum of the squares of the $ x_{i} $, $ i \in \{1, ..., n \} $. I know that the arithmetic mean is $ AM = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{x_{i}} $. And $GM = (x_{1}x_{2}...x_{n})^{\frac {1}{n}}$

Comment: Thanks, oh! no they should have been power $n$ and not square. I have corrected it now.

Comment: Does that show the first inequality? Why?

Answer (score 1):

The first it's AM-GM, which is just Jensen for a concave function $\ln$:
$$\ln\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}\geq \frac{\ln{x_1}+...+\ln{x_n}}{n},$$
which gives $$\ln\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}\geq \ln\sqrt[n]{x_1\cdot...\cdot x_n}$$ or
$$\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}\geq \sqrt[n]{x_1\cdot...\cdot x_n},$$ which for $x_1...x_n=1$ gives:
$$x_1+...+x_n\geq n.$$
The second it's Power Mean inequality, which is Jensen again for the convex function $f(x)=x^k$:
$$\frac{x_1^k+...+x_n^k}{n}\geq\left(\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}\right)^k.$$

Comment: How can I conclude the first inequality from the expression  $$\ln\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}\geq \frac{\ln{x_1}+...+\ln{x_n}}{n}.$$?

Comment: @Jhöśë Elijäh   I added something. See now.

Comment: I think it should be $ -\ln x $ instead of $\ln x$. So I apply Jensen's inequality to the convex function $ -\ln x $ and get $ AM \geq GM $. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But using Jensen for the concave function $\ln$ is shorter.